# How to create Form-Wizard in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to create **form-wizard** or **Step progress bar** when click next button i have to move form-wizard and when click previous button i have to go back form-wizard in angular4. I need like this, see below image

[image]

My pacaage.json
`{
"name": "ph-aware-ng",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.4.7",
"@angular/cdk": "^6.2.1",
"@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/material": "^6.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
"@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2": "^3.3.1",
"@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
"angular2-materialize": "^15.1.10",
"animate": "^1.0.0",
"animation": "^0.1.3",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hamburgers": "^0.9.3",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^2.2.4",
"materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
"moment": "^2.20.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
"ngx-toastr": "^6.5.0",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"sweetalert2": "^7.22.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.4.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^5.3.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
}

Comment: can you show YOUR code

Comment: Kindly show the Code and the image(the link is not present in your question currently.

Comment: @RachitShroff sorry for that..I need form-wizard instead of progress bar... I have updated my question.. Look at my question and give some code .

Comment: @GSreekanth are you open for using angular material?

Comment: @RachitShroff any thinking fine for me...But i need code, I'm new for angular

Answer (score 2):

One of the best ways for implementing Form-Wizard is using Angular Material Stepper.
The detailed information for using stepper is [here](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).

For using material, first follow these steps:

Step 1: Install Angular Material and Angular CDK

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

Run this command in your terminal.

Step 2: Import the component modules.
In your App.module.ts import the material modules that are required.

```
import {MatButtonModule, MatStepperModule,} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatStepperModule,],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Import all required material modules in AppModule. The available options is [here](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/categories)

Step 3: Include a theme. Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application.

If you are using Angular CLI add this in styles.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

For theming guide, refer [this](https://v5.material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Step 4 (Optional): Add Material Icons. It is used for including icons.

For icons, link the following stylesheet in index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Find all the available icons [here](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline)

Now for the stepper or Form-Wizard, here is a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lkdlprrbvlj)

Comment: I'm getting error **ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /Users/sreekanthgudisi/Desktop/stf_angular4/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/sreekanthgudisi/Desktop/stf_angular4/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/sreekanthgudisi/Desktop/stf_angular4/src/app/app.module.ts at syntaxError(/Users/sreekanthgudisi/Desktop/stf_angular4/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)** .Actually my angular version is @angular/cli: **1.4.5**

Comment: when did you get this error? while running or while installing material?

Comment: Share your package.json file. Seems like there are version mismatch.

Comment: I have edited my question and put it package.json file in the question look at that dude...

Comment: The error is because latest versions of material and cdk have been installed. Try running the following commands: "npm uninstall @angular/material @angular/cdk"   followed by "npm install @angular/material@5.2.4 @angular/cdk@5.2.4"

Comment: I did "npm install @angular/material@5.2.4 @angular/cdk@5.2.4"..After that coming same error

Comment: Angular material has been updated and I guess support for angular 4 has been revoked(I may be wrong on this). The best option will be update your application to angular 5 to be able to use material.

Comment: npm install @angular/animations@'^5.0.0' @angular/common@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.0.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.0.0' @angular/core@'^5.0.0' @angular/forms@'^5.0.0' @angular/http@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.0.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.0.0' @angular/router@'^5.0.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'

Comment: Sorry for saying, we r working on angular 4..Please dude try to understand.. Give me some suggestions On angular4.. And also I ran ur command , it's getting another error..

Comment: I have taken open source [ https://github.com/cwun/angular-multi-step-wizard ]..It is working fine